# get new result from sql every week

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a table that I want to pick one row from it and show it to the user. every week I want to make the website automatically picks another row randomly. so, basically I want to get new result every week not every time a user visit the page. 
I am using this code right now :

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$offset = rand(0, $row[0]-1);
/* the first three lines to pick a row randomly from the table */
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fruit LIMIT $offset, 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

This code gets a new result everytime the user visit the page, and after every refresh another random row gets chosen. I want to make it update every week and the results are the same for every user. Is their a php command that does that? If so, how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be as follows:

- Store the *random* result `id` and `timestamp` is some other kind of persistent storage (file, DB table, etc).
- Setup a cron job or other automated task to update the record above *weekly*. If you don't have access to such solutions, you could write code to do it on each page load and check against the `timestamp` column. However, that's pretty inefficient.

Comment: This would be my recommendation too. Read up on CRON jobs and you'll have your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Use the date function in php and write each week and the corresponding row to a file using fwrite. Then, using an if statement, check if it is a new week and if it is get a new random row, write it to the file and return that, if it isn't, return the same one for that week.

Answer (score 0):

A cronjob is the best solution. Create a script `weeklynumber.php`, much as what you have already, that generates an entry. After this, go to your console, and open your crontab file using `crontab -e`.

In here, you may add

```
0 0 * * 0 php /path/to/weeklynumber.php
```

This means that at every Sunday at 0:00, `php /path/to/weeklynumber.php` is executed.

But all of this assumes you're on UNIX and that you have access to creating cronjobs. If not, here's another solution: Hash the week number and year, and use that to generate the weekly number.

```
// Get the current week and year
$week = date('Wy'); 
 // Get the MD5 hash of this
$hash = md5($week);
// Get the amount of records in the table
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fruit"),0);
// Convert the MD5 hash to an integer
$num = base_convert($hash, 16, 10);
// Use the last 6 digits of the number and take modulus $count
$num = substr($num,-6) % $count;
```

Note that the above will only work as long as the amount of records in your table doesn't change.

And finally, just a little note to your current method. Instead of counting rows, getting a random number from PHP, and asking your DBMS to return that number, it can all be done with a single query

```sql
SELECT * FROM fruit ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: also, all what you have did can be done in a single query which is :

    `SELECT * FROM fruit ORDER BY RAND(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%u')+0) Limit 1`

Comment: That's true, `RAND()` is bad on big tables, but so is `COUNT()`.

Comment: `0 0 * * 0 php /path/to/weeklynumber.php` can I put this in a php file? and it will execute by itself

Comment: @shnisaka No, you can put it in your crontab file. When you're SSH'd into your server, or otherwise have access through command line, you write `crontab -e`.